# Load factor too high on SE sites

Tags: support, error-message, performance, concurrency

I'm not sure if this is only happening locally (I would think no, but I would also think it'd have been reported by now if not), but I'm having trouble getting to pages on SE sites. I get the Oops page, and the embedded error message is:

> Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high. The most common cause is multiple threads writing to the Hashtable simultaneously.

It's happened on UL, WA, and Android, both asking a question and just trying to open existing questions. I went back and tried the trilogy; SO and MSO are both fine, but SU and SF have the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sometimes happens to one web server in our web farm when we do a build.

I built again and it went away.

We'll be following up later on this; it might be a bug in the .NET framework itself, somehow:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/d519e8f5-724b-4aa6-b7e6-d400a76898d0/

Comment: It's nice to know that it's not the SO code that's using a `HashTable`!